# A general rule for L'Hôpital's Rule

Tags: real-analysis, limits

In my text there are as many as $11$ theorems dealings with the different cases of L'Hôpital's Rule and due to the quantitative heaviness I often forget rules during problem session. Isn't there a general rule for L'Hôpital's Rule which is easy to remind so that I won't need to spend useless time recalling result?

Comment: What?? 11 cases? This looks like madness to me. I would visit another textbook, at least for this theorem.

Comment: Yes the number is 11. Any better suggestion?

Comment: @SritiMallick Could you tell me what text book are you following?

Comment: Can you show the first four cases, just to get a flavor?

Comment: Usually one or two cases cover the others by manipulation... i.e. one can often transform some 'undefined' limit into one you know how to handle by substituting things or taking logarithms etc. etc.

Comment: Maybe he means cases like $0/0$, $\infty/\infty$, $0\cdot\infty$, $1^\infty$, $0^0$, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

A more general approach would be where 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{d}{dx} f(x)}{\frac{d}{dx} g(x)} 
$$
Or to 0 of course
$$
\lim_{n\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{n\to 0} \frac{\frac{d}{dx} f(x)}{\frac{d}{dx} g(x)} 
$$

Only when $\lim_{n\to \infty/0} f(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty/0} g(x)$ tend towards the same thing ($\infty_{+/-}, 0$)

A good example being

$$
\lim_{x->0} \frac{sin(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{cos(x)}{1} = 1
$$

Answer (score 1):

I think of it as a sort of "algorithm". Let's say you want to calculate the limit of

$$\lim _{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$

If this limit tends to either $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\pm\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, then we apply the rule and differentiate $f$ and $g$ on their own. By this, I mean you don't use the quotient rule, but you just do $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$. Now, you calculate the limit of this. Again, if you get the same thing, you differentiate again.

Let's consider an [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#Examples):

> Evaluate
>
> $$\lim_{x \to 0} {\frac{2\sin (x) -\sin (2x)}{x-\sin (x)}}.$$

Here, we have $f(x) = 2 \sin(x) - \sin(2x)$ and $g(x) = x - \sin (x)$. Straight away, you notice that as $x \to 0$, we get the fraction tending to $\frac{0}{0}$. So we apply L'Hopitals rule:

$$f'(x) = 2\cos (x) -2\cos (2x)$$
$$g'(x) = 1-\cos (x)$$

So now, we are calculating

$$\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{2\cos (x) -2\cos (2x)}{1-\cos (x)}}$$

again, this goes to

$$\frac{2 - 2}{1 - 1} \to \frac{0}{0}$$

and so we apply L'Hopitals again. Now we have:

$$f''(x) = -2\sin (x) +4\sin (2x)$$
$$g''(x) = \sin (x)$$

Now, calulating the limit gives

$$ \lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{-2\sin (x) +4\sin (2x)}{\sin (x)}} \to \frac{0}{0}$$

and so AGAIN, we apply the rule. Differetiating the third time gives us

$$f'''(x) = -2\cos (x) +8\cos (2x)$$
$$g'''(x) = \cos (x)$$

So now taking the limit gives

$$ \lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{-2\cos (x) +8\cos (2x)}{\cos (x)}} \to {\frac{-2 +8}{1}} \to 6.$$